# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at HTMLButtonElement

Tags: javascript, html, dom, typeerror, getelementsbytagname

Can anyone help with this error?

Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:5)
```

html code:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
     <head>
      <title>Eventy</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
     </head>
     <body>
      <ul id="list">
         <li>item 0</li>
      </ul>
      <button id="addElem">Add</button>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

script.js:

```
var add = document.getElementById('addElem');
var list = document.getElementById('Lista'); 

add.addEventListener('click', function(){
list.innerHTML += '<li>item</li>'
});

var newLi = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < newLi.length; i++) {
newLi[i]
}
```

I want to get new 'li' elements after click on button 'Add'. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `Lista !== list` ???

Comment: I have to use length property

Comment: See adeneo's comment -- the script's wrong because the <ul> has an ID of 'list', but the script is referencing 'Lista' as the ID of the object it's collecting.  Change that to 'list' in your script, or change the ID of the <ul> to Lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have an **element** with an ID of **Lista* anywhere.

That is why JavaScript cannot access an element with a non-existent ID thus the property of innerHTML is null.

EDIT: Change the list's variable getElementById value to "list".

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo. You just have to rename `var list = document.getElementById('Lista');` to `var list = document.getElementById('list');` and then it works fine. check it below (click Run Code Snippet) -

```js
var add = document.getElementById('addElem');
var list = document.getElementById('list'); 

add.addEventListener('click', function(){
list.innerHTML += '<li>item</li>'
});

var newLi = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < newLi.length; i++) {
newLi[i]
}
```

```html
 <ul id="list">
            <li>item 0</li>
        </ul>
        <button id="addElem">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) noted in the comments above, you are querying for an element with the id `Lista` when you really want the one with id `list`:

```js
var add = document.getElementById('addElem');
var list = document.getElementById('list');

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  list.innerHTML += '<li>item</li>'
});

var newLi = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < newLi.length; i++) {
  newLi[i]
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <title>Eventy</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>item 0</li>
  </ul>
  <button id="addElem">Add</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```